# Why this macro isnt expanding correctly in msvc c++17 vs2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

This macro isn't expanding as I expected. As long as I have found msvc has possibly the less advantages in terms of macro expansion features but I have been struggling to make this work and I would need to find other points of view to try solving this puzzle. I am also not sure how I came up to this point...

```
#define CONCATENATE(arg1, arg2)   CONCATENATE1(arg1, arg2)
#define CONCATENATE1(arg1, arg2)  CONCATENATE2(arg1, arg2)
#define CONCATENATE2(arg1, arg2)  arg1##arg2

#define FOR_EACH_SFINAE(exec,x) exec(x)
#define FOR_EACH_EXPAND(exec,x,...) exec(x)\
    CONCATENATE(FOR_EACH_,COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_SFINAE(__VA_ARGS__))(exec, __VA_ARGS__)

#define COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_IMPL2(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, count, ...) count
#define COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_IMPL(args) COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_IMPL2 args
#define COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_SFINAE(...) COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_IMPL((__VA_ARGS__,EXPAND,EXPAND,EXPAND,EXPAND,EXPAND,EXPAND,EXPAND,SFINAE,0))
#define COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS(...) COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_IMPL((__VA_ARGS__,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0))

#define FOR_EACH_(N, exec,...) CONCATENATE(FOR_EACH_, N)(exec,__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH(exec,...) FOR_EACH_(COUNT_ASSERT_ARGS_SFINAE(__VA_ARGS__),exec,__VA_ARGS__)

#define OP_BUILDER(method) [](sPointer * pThis, Args...args){ pThis->method(args...); },

#define OP_CREATOR(pointer, method, type, ...)\
template<typename ...Args>\
void method(uint8_t op, const pointer* pThis, Args ...args)\
{\
    typedef const pointer sPointer;\
    static type<Args...> func[] = {\
    FOR_EACH(OP_BUILDER, __VA_ARGS__)\
    };\
    func[op](pThis, args...);\
}

OP_CREATOR(SomeInterface, Method, FuncType, MethodOne, MethodTwo, MethodThree)
```

The wierd thing is that it is working for OP_CREATOR(SomeInterface, Method, FuncType, MethodOne, MethodTwo) but I would like it to support a variable number inputs.

I already know that this way to do things can be archaic but I would really prefer doing it by macros in this case.

I would like it to expand into something like this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void method(uint8_t op, const pointer* pThis, Args ...args)
{
    typedef const pointer sPointer;
    static type<Args...> func[] = {
    [](sPointer * pThis, Args...args){ pThis->MethodOne(args...); },
    [](sPointer * pThis, Args...args){ pThis->MethodTwo(args...); },
    [](sPointer * pThis, Args...args){ pThis->MethodThree(args...); },
    };
    func[op](pThis, args...);
}
```

The bad news is when I come up to the "Expands to:" it appears to be correctly but in last instance it is wrong as shown when I try to compile it.

I am probably missing something... any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using real functions, possibly variadic templates, rather than nasty pre-processor macros?

Comment: Well yes. Indeed I could do it that way. I would prefer to do this via macros, but I begin to think it is not possible...

Comment: "I would prefer to do this via macros" - why? When are macros *ever* the preferred choice, except when they are the *only* choice?

Comment: I would change the word "prefer" by "need" then. I need to do it via macros if it is possible...